# Initialize MATLAB matrix based on indices

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to create a matrix M satisfying:

```
M(i,j) = f(i,j)
```

for some f. I can do elementwise initialization through say `M = zeros(m,n)` then looping. For example (in Octave):

```
M = zeros(m,n)
for i = 1 : m
  for j = 1 : n
    m(i, j) = (i+j)/2;
  endfor
endfor
```

But AFAIK loops are not the  optimal way to go with MATLAB. Any hints?

Comment: One thing: the code above will give you an M+1 by N+1 matrix, not M by N.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure!

```
 xi = 1:m;
 xj = 1:n;
 Ai = repmat(xi',1,length(xj));
 Aj = repmat(xj,length(xi),1);
 M = f(Ai,Aj);
```

You can do this with any `f()` so long as it takes matrix arguments and does element-by-element math. For example: `f = @(i,j) (i+j)/2` or for multiplication: `f = @(i,j) i.*j` The Ai matrix has identical elements for each row, the Aj matrix has identical elements for each column. The [`repmat()` function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/repmat.html) repeats a matrix (or vector) into a larger matrix.

I also edited the above to abstract out vectors `xi` and `xj` -- you have them as `1:m` and `1:n` vectors but they can be arbitrary numerical vectors (e.g. `[1 2 7.0 pi 1:0.1:20]`)

Comment: Thanks! I guess that's similar to what `x` and `y` are in, say, `[x,y] = meshgrid(1:1:m+1)`.

Comment: If `f` can take more than scalar inputs, then `bsxfun` will do this with less typing!

Comment: @Oli: you should add that as another answer!