# Matlab applying operations based on element indices

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, mapping

In Matlab, what is the preferred way to apply operations that make use of the indices of elements they're accessing? Some simple scenarios:

`A(i, j) = A(i, j) + 2*i + 3*j`

`A(i,j) = A(i,j) + A(i+1,j+1)`

Besides using loops, is there any straightforward way to make use of the matrix elements' indices when carrying out operations like these? Answers to similar questions, such as "[Initialize MATLAB matrix based on indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006860/initialize-matlab-matrix-based-on-indices)" make extensive use of `repmat()`. While solutions involving `repmat()` work, it is not easy for someone not proficient in Matlab (such as myself) to develop if the problem is somewhat complicated.

Answer (score 1):

There's often nothing wrong with using a `for` loop, so bear that in mind.

For your first case, I can't think of any solution without using repmat, arrayfun or similar. Something that could work is something like the following:

```
[m,n]=size(A)
A=A+2*ones(m,1)*(1:n)+3*(1:m).'*ones(1,n)
```

using matrix multiplication, but I agree that this is not very obvious!

In your second example, Matlab's indexing can help. It's not clear what you want to happen to elements along the last row/column of A, but you can do something like this:

```
A(1:end-1,1:end-1)=A(1:end-1,1:end-1)+A(2:end,2:end)
```

although you may want to make a new matrix or save your old one if you need to do more things to it.

Your question is quite broad, and there are many techniques, hopefully these two give you some ideas, and don't automatically reject using a for loop either. There are also lots of handy Matlab functions that can help with this sort of thing that you will see pop up in answers here.

Answer (score 1):

For the first case, you could make use of [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html), which is a function which carries out a Binary operation with Singleton Expansion on two arrays. It takes in two arrays and copies along dimensions with `size==1` so that the arrays have the same size, then performs a binary operation on them. For your first example, you can do the following:

```
i = 1:10; % range for the first dimension
j = (1:5)'; % range for the second dimension, note the transpose

A(i, j) = A(i, j) + bsxfun(@plus,2*i,3*j);
```

for the second case, it's a simple matter of doing exactly what you've got there

```
% define i and j - make sure that you won't get an out of bounds error
i = 1:10; % range for the first dimension
j = 2:8; % range for the second dimension

A(i,j) = A(i,j) + A(i+1,j+1)
```